# in which situations we schould write the definition of the function only in the implementation file?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, header-files, formclosing

I have form1 and form2. to open form2 we schould click on the button btn. we use the pointer f2 to pointer to the form2, and we open it using show(this), we use the public function DialogClosed to make f2 point to nullptr.

**in Form1.h i have:**

```
#include "Form2.h"
Private: Form2^ f2;
namespace WinDialog 
{
 private: System::Void btn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^e) 
  {
   if (f2== nullptr)
      {
       f2=gcnew Form2();
       f2->Show(this);
      }
  else
     f2->Activate();
}

public: void DialogClosed( )
  {          
   f2= nullptr;
  }
}
```

**in Form2.h i have:**

```
private:System::Void Form2_FormClosed(Object^ FormClosedEventArgs^e);
```

**in Form2.cpp i have:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
namespace WinDialog
{
  System::Void Form2::Form2_FormClosed(Object^ sender, FormClosedEventArgs^ e)
   {        
    Form1^ temp = (Form1^)this->Owner;
    temp->DialogClosed();//hier we call the public function in Form1.
   }
}
```

My Question: **why we schould write the definiton Form2_FormClosed in the implementation file and not in the header file**. i tried to write the definition in the header file, but it didn't work.
i need your help, please give me your opinion.

Comment: Please fix your tags, your question is C++ not C#.

Answer (score 0):

Header files generally store function definitions.  They can also store method implementations like:

```
inline string method() {
    return something;
}
```

But you have to watch your references.  The most likely reason that your function would not work in the header was that you did not have a reference to the Form1.h header that you needed.  In your Form2 cpp file, you include a reference to Form1.h.  The problem in the case of headers is that you could quickly have a circular dependency.  Form2.h requires a reference to Form1.h, but then Form1.h needs a reference to Form2.h and so on.  So by putting your implementation down in the cpp area, you can provide ALL the header referencing you need without worrying about circular dependencies.